# Selecting multiple options in a form and storing all of the choosen values inside a model using django

Tags: python, django

I am facing problem in Selecting multiple options in a form and storing all of the chosen values inside a model using Django python.
I have created a form in`enter code here` forms.py file :

```
class CustomerSignup(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Customer Name",widget=forms.TextInput(),required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput)
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    time =forms.DateTimeField(label="Time of Arrival",initial=datetime.datetime.today)
    guests = forms.CharField(label="Number of Guests",widget=forms.NumberInput)
    orderList=[

        ('organic tomato salad','organic tomato salad'),
        ('Baked broccoli','Baked broccoli'),
        ('Spicy meatballs','Spicy meatballs'),
        ('Eggplant parmigiana','Eggplant parmigiana'),
        ('Grilled Caesar salad, shaved reggiano','Grilled Caesar salad, shaved reggiano'),
        ('Spicy Calamari and beans','Spicy Calamari and beans'),
        ('>Bacon wrapped wild gulf prawns','>Bacon wrapped wild gulf prawns'),
        ('Seared ahi tuna fillet*, honey-ginger sauce','Seared ahi tuna fillet*, honey-ginger sauce'),
        ('Grilled Caesar salad, shaved reggiano','Grilled Caesar salad, shaved reggiano'),
        ('Spicy Calamari and beans','Spicy Calamari and beans'),
        ('chettinad chicken','chettinad chicken'),
        ('italian salad','italian salad'),
        ('combo of slad with tuna','combo of slad with tuna'),
        ('fried chicken65','fried chicken65'),
        ('hakka noodels','hakka noodels'),
        ('fruit twist','fruit twist'),
        ('garlic chilly chicken','garlic chilly chicken'),
        ('cabbage salad','cabbage salad'),
        ('grlic bread with white soup','grlic bread with white soup'),
        ('lentils and chicken salad','lentils and chicken salad'),
        ('french toast','french toast'),

    ]
    order=forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=orderList))

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    confirm=forms.BooleanField()
```

I have a model corresponding to this form as:

```
models.py

class Registration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    time =models.DateTimeField()
    orders = models.TextField()
    guests = models.IntegerField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Customer details"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to display my selected order items inside my model

Answer (score 0):

From what I see. I think you can move the choices from your form into the model itself like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices), and in your form, you can use the [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead. It'll look like

Model:

```
orderList = [...]

class Registration(models.Model):
    orders = models.TextField(choices=orderList)
    ...
```

Form:

```
class CustomerSignup(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = ('orders ', ...)
        widgets = {
            'orders': SelectMultiple()
        }
```